# relationships in django which one to use

Tags: django, model, relationship

I am having trouble trying to decide what kind of relationship I should use for my application.

I want to have a database that shows something like...

A `Movie` table with fields `title`, `year`, `language`, `description`, `duration` and so on.

A `User` table with fields `username`, `email`

(I am new to django and am not worrying about authentications or passwords or any of that for now)

I want a user to be able to favorite a movie so I am trying to wrap my head around how it would actually work, for instance, would it be a user can favorite many movies and a movie can be favorited by many users (this makes sense to me) or is it a user can favorite many movies and a movie is favorited by a user.

so If I pick the second option I guess it would be a one-to-many rather than the first option which is a many-to-many relationship. However, I am not sure which one is actually correct.

After looking at the docs in django for many-to-one I see that a foreign key should be given to the `Movie` that references a user from `User` but they use an option that has `on_delete=models.CASCADE` and to my understanding it seems like the movie will be deleted if i were to delete the user which of course I don't want.

I was hoping for a detailed explanation as to which relationship it oughta be and if it is a many-to-one relationship then what kind of option should i use for instance the `on_delete=models.CASCADE` is probably not what I should use to my understanding

Comment: You us a `ManyToManyField`.

Comment: will a many-to-many relationship create a table that with fields for the user id and movie id (such as a favorite table with those fields)

Comment: Yes, Django will create an extra table with two `ForeignKey`s: one to each table.

Comment: Okay thanks, I will try that out.

Comment: see the documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField